# If you move to a new town on a different copy of ACNL, do villagers remember you?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

With two different (physical, so they are both being played on separate consoles) copies of Animal Crossing: New Leaf, when your character moves from one town to another, do the villagers from the first town remember you if you go back to visit?

Answer (score 1):

No. Unless a villager from the first town moves out and subsequently moves into your new town. If this is a Mayor moving, then this is not an option. But if you are moving a second player out to be a Mayor of a new town then it's possible.

You'll need to monitor your old town and when someone says they are moving and have their stuff in boxes. Have the Mayor from the new town come and visit them and ask them to move to the second town. As long as you have room in the second town (ie, you don't have all 10 residents used up), they will move over. It takes a couple of days for the move to happen.

One after thought related to the body of your question. Yes, if your new Mayor goes back to the old town where they were previously a resident, the old villagers will remember them.